# error : unable to locate package

Tags: package-management, snort

I have installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine and am trying to install Snort on it. However, it's giving me an error message:

[image: error message]
I tried `sudo apt-get update` command as well but gave me the same error.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [brouhaha](https://www.brouhaha.com/~eric/tgz.html):

> **What is .tar.gz format?**
>
> Under Unix, tar archives are the most common means of distributing
>   bundles of files, and gzip is the most common compression program. A
>   .tar.gz file is simply a bundle of files packaged with tar, and
>   subsequently compressed with gzip.
>
> Sometimes the extension ".tgz" is used as an abbreviation for
>   ".tar.gz". This is especially common on platforms such as MS-DOS that
>   have arbitrary constraints on filenames (no more than one dot, and no
>   more than three characters after the dot).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)):

> Debian packages are standard Unix ar archives that include two tar
>   archives optionally compressed with gzip (zlib), Bzip2, lzma, or xz
>   (lzma2): one archive holds the control information and another
>   contains the program data.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)):

> Ubuntu is a Debian-based Linux operating system and distribution for
>   personal computers, smartphones and network servers.

Since, Ubuntu is a debian-based OS thus, it uses `*.deb` packages to install software but if you want you may install softwares using `.tar.gz` files. But then in that case the commands will be different. Have a look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) for further information.

From [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/apt-get.html):

> The apt-get command is a powerful command-line tool, which works with
>   Ubuntu's Advanced Packaging Tool (APT) performing such functions as
>   installation of new software packages, upgrade of existing software
>   packages, updating of the package list index, and even upgrading the
>   entire Ubuntu system.

So, if you want to install any software in Ubuntu, then you have to type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

In your case it would be:

```
sudo apt-get install snort
```

Comment: If the answer solved your question then, please [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/727043/119531) by clicking on [the upvote arrow and then the tick below it](http://i.imgur.com/YN8AQkd.png?1).

Answer (score 1):

You should provide just the package name to `apt-get`, not a downloaded tarfile. This would install the package version from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install snort
```